# How to extract common function

Tags: reactjs

I have some function that occurs in 4 places (custom hooks) so I want to extract it and save in some /common directory in some file to reuse it in these 4 places. Here is one of my 4 custom hooks with this repeated function:

```
export function useMyHook({changeColumnSorting}) {

const [filters, setFilters] = useState();

function handleOnColumnSortChange(columnName, order) {
        changeColumnSorting?.(columnName, order);
        const newFilters = {
            ...filters,
            sorting: { [columnName]: order },
        };
        setFilters(newFilters);
    }

return {
        sorting: filters.sorting,
        filters,
        handleOnColumnSortChange
}
```

`columnName` and `order` are unknown, passed from some third party table where `handleOnColumnSortChange` is one of parameters (here in some other component `useMyHook` is used):

```
const { handleOnColumnSortChange} =
        useMyHook({
            changeColumnSorting
        });

<Table
 handleOnColumnSortChange={handleOnColumnSortChange} 
/>
```

How to extract this function in some file and return this function in all my 4 hooks?

Params are mixed, some params are given from external Table and some variables used in this function are declared in this particular hook... That's the problem

My attempt:

extracted function:

```
export function handleOnColumnSortChange(
    columnName: string,
    order: any,
    changeColumnSorting: any,
    filters: any,
    setFilters: (data: any) => void
) {
    changeColumnSorting?.(columnName, order);
    const newFilters = {
        ...filters,
        sorting: { [columnName]: order },
    };
    setFilters(newFilters);
}
```

but what next?
the first 2 params are undefined, I tried to create some const with similar name like my common function and return it in my hook:

[image]

Comment: Where is `changeColumnSorting` from?

Comment: updated my code - `changeColumnSorting` is a parameter of my hook

Comment: your last screenshot is an invocation, not passing the reference of the function to `handleOnColumnSortChangeFunction`

Comment: @damonholden I updated my code, in my last screenshot I tried to change my repeated function `handleOnColumnSortChange` in one of my custom hooks by creating some new const and adding some params to it but i have no idea... Probably its impossible and I will have to stick with this function repeated in 4 custom hooks

Comment: It really depends on how exactly this component library is consuming your callback. Any chance of a sandbox to assist further?